# Dimming Lights without PWM. Possible? Using Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, home-automation

I'm using a Raspberry Pi to dim a light, using python to get 0%....50%...100% and various % brightnesses in between.
Taking a PWM approach in the code means a flickering light, which won't work for the lower % brightness, as the flicker will become more apparent. I can't seem to find a method to code brightness level without PWM, but there must be! Any suggestions gratefully received!
(this is my first go at coding with python and trying to see what is possible)

Comment: how do you expect that to work on the electrical side? Please share your code and circuit diagram

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because dimming lights is about electrics and not about software development.

Comment: ask on https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: you should increase the frequency of your pwm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want that many level of brightness PWM is your only option. Don't worry you won't notice the flicker anyway. If you don't want to use PWM then you will have to construct external circuit, for each brightness level you will have to calculate the voltage and add voltage divider according to it. Then  Switch between them from raspberry pi code. you can do this for 100 brightness level if you want but it will be a big mess. Use this if you are okay with 3-4 levels of brightness